# hook for dashboard show_user_profile

Tags: functions, dashboard

I'm looking a way to avoid regular users go to profile and dashboard page.
Have this little code to work with profile page:

```
function lockdown_profile()
{
    global $current_user;
    return !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ? wp_redirect("/profile") : true;
}
add_action('show_user_profile', "lockdown_profile");
```

And works, but i need to do the same for dashboard page, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show_user_profile` is the wrong hook to use.  You should redirect before anything gets sent to the browser (eg. before headers are sent).

Fortunately there are actions that happen much earlier: `load-{$pagename}` is the one you want.  So you can hook into `load-index.php` and `load-profile.php` to throw people back to the front end.

```
<?php
add_action( 'load-profile.php', 'wpse35742_maybe_redirect' );
add_action( 'load-index.php', 'wpse35742_maybe_redirect' );
function wpse35742_maybe_redirect()
{
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) return;
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/profile' ), 302 );
    exit();
}
```

All that said, you would be better off [adding a new role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) that has even more limited capabilities than the typical subscribers: don't let them view the dashboard or their profiles (the `read` capability).